# Angular2 view not updating when receiving data from rest api and mapping to hash map

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I have a hash map that I use for the content of my app - basically I have a service, get some data from a JSON file, Map it and then use that to fill my views. In the future I would like have have i18n support in my app. Now some of the content comes from a 3rd party REST API. I connect to this in another service, fetch the information using http, format is then add it to the content hash map. When I output this to the console the new data is there and aggregated to the data from my JSON file. However my view isn't updated. In AngularJS I may run a `$scope.apply()` or `$scope.digest()` at this stage but we don't use those in Angular2. Can anyone see what I am missing.

Here is the original ContentService I call when starting the app:

```
@Injectable()
export class ContentService {
    content: Observable<Map<string, Card>>;
    userLang: string;

    constructor(public http:Http) {
        this.userLang = 'en';
        this.content = this.http.get('src/i18n/' + this.userLang + '.json')
            .map((res:Response) => {
                let json: {} = res.json();
                return this.mapData(json);
            })
    }

    mapData(json:any):Map<string, Card> {
        // stuff happens here
    }
```

This is the service I wrote to fetch the API content then add it to my original content

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

    constructor(public http:Http, public contentService: ContentService) {

        contentService.content
            .flatMap((contentMap:Map<string, Card>) => {
                return this.formatAllCurrentListings().map((json):Map => {

                    Object.keys(json).forEach((a) => {
                        let contentCard = new ExtendedCard(
                            '',
                            json[a].header,
                            json[a].contentMaster,
                            json[a].contentDetail
                        );
                        contentMap.set(a, contentCard);
                    });
                    return contentMap;
                });
            })
            .subscribe((res) => {
                console.log(res); // the new content is in the response, but my view isn't updated
                return res
            });
    }

    public formatAllCurrentListings():Observable<ApiListings> {
        let url:string = 'apiur.com/rest/listings';

        return this.http.get(url)
            .map((response:Response) => this.formatListings(response.json()))
            .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount();
    }
```

Although I have no errors and the content is delivered, is of the correct format, the view doesn't load it! Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? How can I get the view to add the new content, do I have to emit an event or something?

Comment: How does your view look like? I don't see where you connect the data with the view.

Comment: I actually bind it to the view with a common service that searches / iterates through the map looking for a key. When doing the search although the Map contains the new data when I console out when I search the Map elsewhere in my app the data cannot be found?

Comment: Please add the code to your question that shows what and how you are doing it.

Comment: I think the real problem is that I want to update the data in the Content Service after the flatMap in the ApiService. I'll put the code online somewhere as there is too much to post here...